# Let $x,w,v,u$ vectors in vector space $V$ that satisfy: $\text{span}\{u,v\} = \text{span}\{w,x\}$ then:

Tags: linear-algebra

> 1. $v,u$ are linearly independent
> 2. $\text{span}\{u,v,w\} = \text{span}\{v,w,x\}$
> 3. $\text{span}\{u,x\} = \text{span}\{v,x\}$

I don't understand why 2 is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

We obviously have $w\in\operatorname{span}\{w,x\}$. But by assumption, $\operatorname{span}\{w,x\}=\operatorname{span}\{u,v\}$, therefore $w\in\operatorname{span}\{u,v\}$. But then adding $w$ to $\operatorname{span}\{u,v\}$ clearly doesn't add anything new (it's already in there), therefore $\operatorname{span}\{u,v,w\}=\operatorname{span}\{u,v\}$.

Now apply an analogous argumentation to the right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

The example $u=v=w=x=(1,0)$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$ shows that $u$ and $v$ need not be independent. So 1) is false.

The example $v=w=(1,0), u=x=(0,1)$ shows that 3) is false.

To prove that 2) is true just verify that each side is contained in the other.